# MediaStore doesn't give me size, resolution, duration, and date of video files

Tags: android, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I'm trying to retrieve info about user videos stored in sdcard, and I've this method:

```
protected void addVideo () {
    cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            mediaColumns, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int i = 1;



        do {

            VideoItem newVVI = new VideoItem();
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
            newVVI.idthumb = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails._ID));
            Cursor thumbCursor = cr.query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID
                            + "=" + id, null, null);
            if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));

            }
            newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
            newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
            try {
                newVVI.date = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                newVVI.date = "0";
            }
            try {
                newVVI.duration = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                newVVI.duration = "0";
            }
            try {
                newVVI.size = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                newVVI.size = "0";
            }
            try {
                newVVI.resolution = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                newVVI.resolution = "0";
            }

            newVVI.mimeType = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE));

            newVVI.id = Integer.toString(i);
            ITEMS.add(newVVI);
            ITEM_MAP.put(newVVI.id, newVVI);
            i++;


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();


    } else {
        Log.d("TEST", ": else);
    }



}
```

The problem is that for MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, and MediaStore.Video.Media.RESOLUTION I got always "0" because for these I always catch the IllegalArgumentException.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The values are 0 because that is the default and they were never set to be anything else.
The MediaStore does not automatically calculate these values when a video is copied to sdcard.

For duration you could try using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getDuration%28%29) to load the video and then call getDuration.

Answer (score 0):

this code return info from one special audio.but it worked truely.
you can change it acording to my main Question whit while statement for get all audios or videos.
you must change MediaStore.audio in my response to Mediastore.Video.

```
String name="";
String duration="";
String path="";
Log.d("Loading file: " + filepath,"");

        // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
        // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
        // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
Uri audiosUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external");

Log.d("audiosUri = " + audiosUri.toString(),"");

String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION};

// TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(audiosUri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filepath }, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

path =cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
name=cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
int iduration = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[2]);
duration=CalTotalTime(Integer.valueOf(iduration));
Log.d("pathhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh", path);
Log.d("nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", name);
Log.d("duration", duration);

cursor.close();
```

see this link too:
[get your info from files by mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127865/i-want-to-get-a-cursor-to-one-file-only-but-howsolved)